# Cordova Add Platform fails due to spaces in User Name

Tags: cordova, windows-7, blackberry-10

I'm on Windows 7 and using Cordova 3.4.1 to make an app. Android worked fine.

Now I was adding BlackBerry 10

My command

cordova platform add blackberry10

gives following error:

```
    Creating blackberry10 project...
'C:\Users\Basit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: C:\Users\Basit Ali\.cordova\lib\blackberry10\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat
: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Basit Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I can figure out what's wrong. It's actually my user name that has spaces in it. My full user name on Windows is "Basit Ali" while the command fails at the space in above error.

I'm sure a fix will come in future versions but is there a workaround to following ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and the only workaround was to change the Windows account!
I know that's not the best option, but I ran into this problem with many other softwares so I decided to change the name (created a new account).